# Get days in a week

Tags: sql, datetime, pivot, counting

There is the table with the list of random days (in *datetime* format)

```
          date
-----------------------
1935-24-25 00:00:00.000
1987-56-15 00:00:00.000
1956-08-05 00:00:00.000
1974-57-25 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: You are conflating two issues here. The first is simply to return how often each weekday occurs in a given yearmonth. The second is about hosw you would then like to display that result which, I would argue, would be more properly handled in application code.

Comment: Hi, show us what you have got so far.

Comment: `COUNT(IF(WEEKDAY(date)=0,1,null)) as Mon, ...`

Comment: MySQL does not have pivot statement. Are you sure that your question is related to MySQL?

Comment: Added my code, not sure how to get other days right

Answer (score 3):

By observation:

If a month begins on a Monday then there are 4 Thursdays, Fridays, Saturdays and Sundays in that month.

If the month has 28 days, then there are also 4 Mondays, Tuesdays, and Wednesdays in it.

If the month has 29 days, then there are 5 Mondays, and 4 Tuesdays and Wednesdays.

If the month has 30 days, then there are 5 Mondays and Tuesdays, and 4 Wednesdays.

Finally,if the month has 31 days, then there are 5 Mondays, Tuesdays, and Wednesdays.

We can substitute 'Monday' above for day 'A', where day 'A' is whatever day of the week the month starts on.

So all we need to know is the day of the week the month began on, and the number of days in the month. So not really any SQL at all.